# Convert BYTE to BSTR in VSS Hardware framework c++

Tags: c++, windows

I need page83 Information in the commit snapshot method

While am doing the vss trace, i get the page83 for the Drive, and i need m_rgbIdentifier

```
BEGIN VDS_LUN_INFORMATION for \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1: rgLunInformation[0]
BEGIN VDS_STORAGE_DEVICE_ID_DESCRIPTOR m_deviceIdDescriptor[0] BEGIN
VDS_STORAGE_IDENTIFIER m_rgIdentifiers[0,0] m_rgbIdentifier:
```

Where the m_rgbIdentifier is BYTE

```
typedef struct _VDS_STORAGE_IDENTIFIER
    {
    VDS_STORAGE_IDENTIFIER_CODE_SET m_CodeSet;
    VDS_STORAGE_IDENTIFIER_TYPE m_Type;
    ULONG m_cbIdentifier;
    /* [size_is] */ BYTE *m_rgbIdentifier;
    }   VDS_STORAGE_IDENTIFIER;
```

and the BYTE

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

How to convert the m_rgbIdentifier to any String type and pass to REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `BYTE *m_rgbIdentifier;` says that `m_rgbIdentifier` is a `BYTE *`, **not a `BYTE`**.

So it is an `unsigned char *`. Simply it is not (guaranteed to be) null terminated, but its length is given in `m_cbIdentifier`.

Provided there is no null in it, you can convert is to a plain C string (`char *`) with :

```
char * str = new char[m_cbIdentifier + 1];
memcpy(str, m_rgbIdentifier, m_cbIdentifier);
str[m_cbIdentifier] = 0;
```

If you need true BSTR, you should use `SysAllocString` :

```
int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, m_rgbIdentifier,
    m_cbIdentifier, NULL, 0);
LPWSTR w = new WCHAR[len];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, m_rgbIdentifier,
    m_cbIdentifier, w, len);
BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(w);
delete[] w;
```

The BSTR must then be freed with `SysFreeString`.

EDIT :

This answer only has sense only if `m_CodeSet` in the structure has the value `VDSStorageIdCodeSetAscii` = 2. And the C string obtained in first way is a plain ANSI string. If you need to convert it to Unicode, you must use `MultiByteToWideChar`. The `LPWSTR w` obtained in 2nd piece of code is a Unicode (wchar_t) C string.

Comment: First way is not working.... am new to c++, 
i tried
char *str = new char[rgLunInformation[0].m_deviceIdDescriptor.m_rgIdentifiers->m_cbIdentifier + 1];
   memcpy(str, rgLunInformation[0].m_deviceIdDescriptor.m_rgIdentifiers->m_rgbIdentifier, rgLunInformation[0].m_deviceIdDescriptor.m_rgIdentifiers->m_cbIdentifier);
   str[rgLunInformation[0].m_deviceIdDescriptor.m_rgIdentifiers->m_cbIdentifier] = 0;


   restClient->HWProviderlogger(Logger(L"lunserial %S", NewString(str)));

Log : lunserial `Dð^L